# Can anyone help me identify a story about squirrels and the octal system?

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a book when I was a kid (age 7-9) about squirrels (or maybe other small animals) that were using the octal numeral system.

Counting to 7 (since 8 = 0) was a whole new magical world that opened for me back then, until I found out a bit later that this numeral system existed for real.

A quick search on the internet gave me nothing, but maybe you can help?

Comment: I vaguely remember something like this, and although I would have sworn they were badgers, I haven't had any more luck tracking it down than you have.

Comment: I don't know how old you are, but maybe it was one of the Penrose the Mathematical Cat stories?

Comment: You can see my age on my profile ;) And no, it was just a regular story about a group of animals (no cats sorry), living their life with their own mathematical (octal) system.

Comment: Were there any spaceships involved? We're going to find this. We must.

Comment: I'm so curious about this story. BOUNTY'D.

Comment: Was it illustrated or was it a young adult book?

Comment: I don't remember illustrations, but it's been a long time. If it had them, they were a minimal part of the book I'm thinking of - it certainly wasn't "Dr. Seuss in the Magical Land of the Octal-counting Badgers."

Comment: It was mainly text indeed, however I do remember they had some special signs for their numbers that where shown on a few pages (but not too often). They could have been some foreign equivalent of our digits (like e.g. old Hindu), but they're to vague in my memory to draw/recognize.

Comment: Was the story *just* about numbers? Or was there a wider storyline?

Comment: There was a wider storyline, but don't ask me which one. Maybe TML remembers.

Comment: Are you sure you're not remembering Watership Down, about rabbits who counted in base-4?

Comment: Quite sure it was base-8. And 400+ pages seems a bit much to read at age 7-9. I expect it more to be in the range of 150 pages.

Comment: I see that you are from Belgium, which language did you read this in?

Comment: I read it in Dutch, but I'm pretty sure it's available in English and other languages too, since TML remembers the plot vaguely too.

Comment: It definitely was not Watership Down, and I read it in English.

Comment: Someone has posted this query on [Stump - A456: Anthropomorphic rodents (perhaps squirrels or badgers) who use a base 8 (0-7, or "octal") counting system](http://logan.com/harriett/stump.html)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be *Mrs. Frisby and the Rats of NiMH*. There's some base 8 counters in this big [TV Tropes list](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FourFingeredHands), but  nothing that matches this question. (We're looking for an ~1992 or earlier book.)

Comment: We need [Watson](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFR3lOm_xhE).

Comment: The images I remember were about the numerals. Very similar to the folk etymology of the arabic numerals but with the addition of counting the angles by putting nuts in them. There's a thread on snopes discussing this http://message.snopes.com/showthread.php?t=49183

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The question has been up on [stump - A456](http://logan.com/harriett/stump.html) for over a month and got a new reply:

> Tod, Michael, The Woodstock Saga, 1990s, approximate. The Woodstock
>   Saga, also known as the Dorset Squirrels, is a series of three novels
>   about a society of squirrels (the titles are The Silver Tide,  The
>   Second Wave  and The Golden Flight). In the first book, the heroine
>   squirrel develops a Base 8 system of counting  inspired by the number
>   of toes she has on her front paws. I hope this helps! :)

- The name Michael Tod sounds familiar to me, so that's a +1.
- It's about squirrels: +1
- They have a Base 8 system: +1

Quite convinced that this is what we were looking for :)

These are the books:

- [http://www.amazon.co.uk/Silver-Tide-Woodstock-Saga/dp/1857975634](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857975634)
- [http://www.amazon.co.uk/Second-Wave-Woodstock-Saga/dp/1857977408](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857977408)
- [http://www.amazon.co.uk/Golden-Flight-Woodstock-saga/dp/0752806181](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0752806181)

Think I've read the 2nd one long ago, as soon as I'm back in the country, I'm gonna try and find all 3. Thanks a lot to the person that posted it on stump.

Comment: +1 It's great that this question is finally answered! :)

Comment: Yeah, I remembered enjoying this book enough that I thought it would be well worth the $2 if that service could identify it for me, so I posted it to them the day after @Anna Lear's bounty expired; looks like it was a good decision! This is definitely the series I was thinking of (and kudos to Bart for getting the right kind of rodent the first time around!) I even remember the grey squirrels being the antagonists now.

Comment: @TML thanks a lot ! And yeah, the grey squirrels ... so gonna buy the series when I get home again.